# How to find average of strings while using k means clustering?

Tags: filter, cluster-analysis, k-means, spam, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to build a message spam filter using `k-means` and `Levenshtein distance` (consider this mandatory). I am having a problem understanding how can I compute the average of 'strings' when I have to figure out the centroid for each cluster?

Answer (score 0):

K-means *cannot* be used on strings.

It minimizes least-squares by computing the arithmetic mean. That is only defined (and meaningful) on **continuous variables**.

On strings you could use PAM aka k-medoids instead.